# How to compare a matrix element with its neighbours without using a loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have a matrix in MATLAB. I want to check the 4-connected neighbours (left, right, top, bottom) for every element. If the current element is less than any of the neighbours then we set it to zero otherwise it will keep its value. It can easily be done with loop, but it is very expensive as I have thousands of these matrices.

You might recognize it as nonmaxima suppression after edge detection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is with the function [NLFILTER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/nlfilter.html) from the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/), which applies a given function to each M-by-N block of a matrix:

```
>> A = magic(6)  %# A sample matrix

A =

    35     1     6    26    19    24
     3    32     7    21    23    25
    31     9     2    22    27    20
     8    28    33    17    10    15
    30     5    34    12    14    16
     4    36    29    13    18    11

>> B = nlfilter(A,[3 3],@(b) b(5)*all(b(5) >= b([2 4 6 8])))

B =

    35     0     0    26     0     0
     0    32     0     0     0    25
    31     0     0     0    27     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
    30     0    34     0     0    16
     0    36     0     0    18     0
```

The above code defines an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) which uses [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#f1-85511) to get the center element of a 3-by-3 submatrix `b(5)` and compare it to its 4-connected neighbors `b([2 4 6 8])`. The value in the center element is multiplied by the logical result returned by the function [ALL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/all.html), which is 1 when the center element is larger than all of its nearest neighbors and 0 otherwise.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for...
I hope its performance is better than the loop :)
thanks gnovie

Comment: +1 for getting it right in the first try, though I suspect that imdilate might still be faster.

Comment: @Jonas: You may be right about the speed, since [IMDILATE performance has seen some significant improvements in the last few versions of MATLAB](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/04/23/more-r2010a-performance-improvements-in-image-processing-toolbox/).

Comment: I wanted to delete all 1s from the matrix which have at least one 0 neighbour, so I changed this code to the following `B = nlfilter(A,[3 3],@(b) b(5)*(0<sum(b([2 4 6 8])) && sum(b([2 4 6 8]))<4));` and it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

If you have the image processing toolbox, you can do this with a [morpological dilation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imdilate.html) to find local maxima and suppress all other elements.

```
array = magic(6); %# make some data

msk = [0 1 0;1 0 1;0 1 0]; %# make a 4-neighbour mask

%# dilation will replace the center pixel with the 
%# maximum of its neighbors
maxNeighbour = imdilate(array,msk);

%# set pix to zero if less than neighbors
array(array<maxNeighbour) = 0;

array =
    35     0     0    26     0     0
     0    32     0     0     0    25
    31     0     0     0    27     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
    30     0    34     0     0    16
     0    36     0     0    18     0
```

*edited to use the same data as @gnovice, and to fix the code*

Comment: thanks for the answer 
this is a cool way but not what i am looking for... consider the following loops
for ( y = 1; y < height - 1; ++y) {
     for ( x = 1; x < width - 1; ++x) {
       if (response[y][x] < response[y][x+1] ||
    result[y][x] < result[y][x-1] ||
    result[y][x] < result[y+1][x] ||
    result[y][x] < result[y-1][x])
      tmp[y][x] = 0.0;
     }
   }

Comment: @Shan: Oops, yes. I fixed the solution.

Comment: +1 For a solution that is about an order of magnitude faster than mine, but this may be because NLFILTER seems to keep briefly displaying a progress bar when I run it (and unnecessary graphics like that are sure to slow things down).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have access to the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/), another way to accomplish this is by constructing four matrices representing the top, right, bottom and left first differences for each point and then searching for corresponding elements in all four matrices that are non-negative (i.e. the element exceeds all of its neighbours).

Here's the idea broken down...

Generate some test data:

```
>> sizeA = 3;
A = randi(255, sizeA)

A =

   254   131    94
   135    10   124
   105   191    84
```

Pad the borders with zero-elements:

```
>> A2 = zeros(sizeA+2) * -Inf;
A2(2:end-1,2:end-1) = A

A2 =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0   254   131    94     0
     0   135    10   124     0
     0   105   191    84     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

Construct the four first-difference matrices:

```
>> leftDiff = A2(2:end-1,2:end-1) - A2(2:end-1,1:end-2)

leftDiff =

   254  -123   -37
   135  -125   114
   105    86  -107

>> topDiff = A2(2:end-1,2:end-1) - A2(1:end-2,2:end-1)

topDiff =

   254   131    94
  -119  -121    30
   -30   181   -40

>> rightDiff = A2(2:end-1,2:end-1) - A2(2:end-1,3:end)

rightDiff =

   123    37    94
   125  -114   124
   -86   107    84

>> bottomDiff = A2(2:end-1,2:end-1) - A2(3:end,2:end-1)

bottomDiff =

   119   121   -30
    30  -181    40
   105   191    84
```

Find the elements that exceed all of the neighbours:

```
indexKeep = find(leftDiff >= 0 & topDiff >= 0 & rightDiff >= 0 & bottomDiff >= 0)
```

Create the resulting matrix:

```
>> B = zeros(sizeA);
B(indexKeep) = A(indexKeep)

B =

   254     0     0
     0     0   124
     0   191     0
```

After wrapping this all into a function and testing it on 1000 random 100x100 matrices, the algorithm appears to be quite fast:

```
>> tic;
for ii = 1:1000
A = randi(255, 100);
B = test(A);
end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.861121 seconds.
```

Comment: +1: Very nice. It's easy to forget about simpler implementations like this when you have access to fancy toolboxes. ;) One suggestion... you can simplify your code using [CIRCSHIFT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/circshift.html) like so: `index = A2>=circshift(A2,[0 1]) & A2>=circshift(A2,[0 -1]) & A2>=circshift(A2,[1 0]) & A2>=circshift(A2,[-1 0]); A2 = A2.*index; A2 = A2(2:end-1,2:end-1);` Also, I think you want to use `>=` instead of `>`.

Comment: Oh, and another suggestion to make the algorithm more general would be to use `-Inf` to pad your matrix instead of 0, to account for the possibility of negative values in your matrix (i.e. you don't want padding to ever show up as a local maxima).

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks for the suggestions. Edited to include them. Didn't implement CIRCSHIFT just to keep the gruntier approach but I agree that using CIRCSHIFT would be a nicer solution.