# Matlab: find neighboring instances of NaN without loops

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, nan

Essentially, I have a matrix of data with many "holes" represented by NaN, and I want to retrieve the indices of all NaN's that are clustered *fewer* than 4 times in a single column.

e.g. with the matrix:

```
A = 
    23    12    NaN   56    60    21    NaN
    60    56    94    22    45    NaN   NaN
    23    55    19    83    NaN   NaN   NaN
    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    84    99    43    32    89    12    NaN
    76    92    73    47    22    12    10
    23    55    12    93    61    94    20
    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    41    16    83    39    82    37    43
    14    78    92    40    81    29    60
```

it would return:

```
ans = 
    [4; 5; 6; 10; 16; 17; 18; 22; 25; 28; 29; 30; 34; 40; 41; 42; 46; 58; 70; 82]
```

So far, I have a vector with the indices of all the NaN values from

```
nan_list=find(isnan(A(:)))
```

but I don't know how to extract sequential numbers from that vector without using loops, which would be too expensive. I also tried something similar to the answer posted by b3 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042594/comparing-matrix-element-with-its-neighbours-without-using-loop-in-matlab), by switching all NaN's to a value that doesn't appear in the matrix, but that code was not as transferable for other data sets.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Your clusters of NaN fewer than 4, can overlap, or they you look in on-overlapping clusters of 4? Also what your `ans` represents. Cant see connection to `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code**

```
N = 4; %// Fewer than clusters of N or N+ NaNs are to be detecteed
nan_pos = isnan(A) %// Find NaN positions as a binary array
conv_res = conv2(double(nan_pos),[0 ones(1,N)]')==N %//' Perform convolution
start_ind = find(conv_res(N+1:end,:)) %// Find positions where clusters of N or N+ NaNs start
nan_pos(unique(bsxfun(@plus,start_ind,[0:N-1])))=0 %// Get positions of all those clustered N or N+ NaNs and set them in NaN position array as zeros
out = find(nan_pos) %// Finally the desired output
```

**Example**

As an example, let's try this code on a slightly different input that would hopefully test out various aspects of the problem -

```
A = [
    23    12    NaN   56    60    21    NaN
    60    56    94    22    45    NaN   NaN
    23    55    19    83    NaN   NaN   NaN
    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    84    99    43    32    89    12    NaN
    76    92    73    47    22    12    10
    23    55    12    93    61    94    20
    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
    41    NaN   NaN    39    82    37   43
    14    78    NaN    40    81   NaN   60]
```

Now, let's assume that we are looking to find indices of cluster fewer than `3 NaNs`. Thus editing `N` as `3` in the code, the output is -

```
out =
    10    22    23    25    46    58    70    72    82
```

This makes sense when we look into the input.

Comment: I tested this with the input `A` from the question and it produces the desired result. Nice use of convolution. +1

Comment: @kkuilla Appreciate the UP! :)

Comment: Btw, doesn't `conv` wrap around the columns so that the last value of the 6th column be convolved with the NaNs in the 7th column? This is what I would expect but it doesn't as your code works.

Comment: @kkuilla `conv2` won't wrap around, as I am using a "column filter" - `[0; 1; 1; 1; 1]` with it. This is coherent with the question that states - `fewer than 4 times in a single column`. So asker doesn't want wrapping around onto the next column.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you are blocking the wrapping by creating a kernel that will be limited to columns only. That is nice. :-)

Comment: ah, I like the conv approach. works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[rows, ~] = size(A);
maxNansPerCol = 4;

% find which columns have few enough NaNs
Anans = isnan(A);
nansInCols = sum(Anans);
qualifyingCols = nansInCols <= maxNansPerCol;

% zero the other columns
mask = repmat(qualifyingCols,rows,1);
B = Anans .* mask;

% get the NaN locations
indices = find(B(:));
```

(Apologies if something is slightly off--I don't have MATLAB on this computer to test it)

Comment: Your code does not generate the expected outcome. This is what your code produces with the input `A` as stated in the original question: [4 5 6 10 16 17 18 22 40 41 42 46]

Comment: Ah. You mean 4 _sequential_ NaNs in a column. Yes, the above convolution approach is probably want you want then (and if so, I suggest accepting his answer).